# controller doesn't receive id param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am trying to display a page that shows the users that liked a micropost. I want the Uri to be localhost:3000/microposts/someid#/into_it. It seems as through the path is not responding to the controller?

I link to this page in a view/microposts/_micropost.html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to micropost.votes_for, into_it_micropost_path(@micropost) %>
```

Due to this path i receive the following error in my browser and the page does not load:

```
No route matches {:action=>"into_it", :controller=>"microposts", :id=>nil}
```

In my microposts controller:

```
def into_it  #for the view; displays who likes the post
  @title = "Into_it!"
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  render 'show_users_into_it'
end
```

micropost/show_users_into_it is a blank file currently

Routes file:

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy, :into_it] do
  member do
    get :into_it
  end
end
```

In rake routes I have:

```
into_it_micropost GET    /microposts/:id/into_it(.:format)     microposts#into_it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a silly mistake really. the route wasn't getting the id param. what i had to do was simply change:

```
into_it_micropost_path(@micropost)
```

to

```
into_it_micropost_path(micropost.id)
```

so that it gets the id from the existing record in the database

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because of not valid @micropost. @micropost should be an object from database. It should have an id. In your error message you can see that id of micropost is nil(I guess @micropost is new record).

```
:id=>#<Micropost id: nil
```

If you pass existing @micropost everything will be fine.

Comment: No, he is saying, that you should hide this link if @micropost is a new record

Comment: it's not a new record. I just want to find the users who liked an existing record of a micropost and display the users

Comment: If it's not a new record, why id is nil? It cann't be so. Check @micropost. You can check by calling `@micropost.new_record?`. Comment link and check @micropost